# Confused as of why when I used independence in early steps I got a wrong answer in this question.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

**The Question:**

> The number of people entering a restaurant is a random variable $N$ with poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=36$. 
> every one of the people enjoys his/her meal with a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ independently from the number of people that entered the restaurant and other people's decisions (enjoyed or not). 
> Find the probability function of the number of people that enjoyed their meal given that the number of people entered the restaurant is $n$. in other words, if $E$ is a random variable that counts how many people enjoyed their meal, then find $P(G=k|N=n)$.

**The Way I solved it:** 
Since it's said that the people which enjoy their meal are independent of the number of people that entered the restaurant, what I did is simply: $P(G=k|N=n)=P(G=k)$ , and I know that $G\sim Pois(\frac{1}{3}*36)$. 

**The Answer:** 
They introduced $I_i$ indicator random variable that is equal to $1$ whenever person $i$ enjoyed his meal and $0$ when not. 
And so $$P(G=k|N=n)=P(\sum_{j=0}^{N}I_i=k | N=n)=P(\sum_{j=0}^{n}I_i=k | N=n)=P(\sum_{j=0}^{n}I_i=k)={n \choose k}(\frac{1}{3})^k(\frac{2}{3})^{n-k}$$
Notice that they did also use the independence in step 3. 
**My Confusion and my thoughts:**
I completely understand the idea behind the answer, and intuitively I understand why it's correct, as we're setting the number of trials to $n$, and so it's no longer infinite, and thus it turns into a binomial distribution whether each person enjoyed their meal or not with $n$ trials. 

What confuses me is wheres my mistake? why when I used the independence at the first step it completely gave me a wrong answer, I know that it made me lose the given information that $N=n$, but it was said that they're not dependent, so why did I get this outcome? 
Any help in clearing this confusion is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In the quoted problem statement, how is $G$ related to $E$, the random variable that counts how many people enjoyed their meal?

Comment: The distribution of the number of people is irrelevant to the problem  We are told that $n$ showed up.  It makes no difference how likely that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question says that the probability of a person enjoying their meal is independent of the number of people in the restaurant. It does **not** say that the **number** of people enjoying their meal is independent of the number of people in the restaurant.